# Resolving git conflict visual studio 2013

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013, synchronization

I'm trying to pull the most recent version of my group's app from visual studio online.  Unfortunately, when I try to pull it, I'm getting this [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FVkiw.png).  I read a couple tutorials, and most of them tell you to merge your conflict.  But I don't even see a merge screen or button, and visual studio's just saying I have those conflicts but doesn't give me any option to fix it.  I'm also not trying to push my most recent changes yet, so I think I also have the option of undoing my changes, but I don't see an option to do this.

Comment: You should always copy/paste everything in your question. The link you provided exists no more.

Answer (score 1):

You have *checkout conflicts*.  Which is to say that Visual Studio is detecting a bunch of modified files in your working directory.

You haven't made any changes to any files, you say?  Right.  It turns out that Visual Studio 2013 has a bug where it detects your incorrect line ending configuration as changes.

Upgrade to VS 2013 Update 4 and you will be able to continue on with your incorrect line ending configuration.

However you should really make sure that everybody on your team is using the correct line ending settings.  *Don't* rely on `core.autocrlf`.  *Do* set up your desired line endings in `.gitattributes`.  Then *do* rewrite every file in the repository to have line endings that match what you have specified in `.gitattributes`.

The GitHub article "[Dealing With Line Endings](https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings/)" should help.

Answer (score 0):

Git [pull](https://git-scm.herokuapp.com/docs/git-pull) will not work if you have conflicting local changes.

> If any of the remote changes overlap with local uncommitted changes,
>   the merge will be automatically cancelled and the work tree untouched.
>   It is generally best to get any local changes in working order before
>   pulling or stash them away with git-stash.

I recommend that you check in your local changes, and then pull and merge the latest.  You don't need to push your local changes (Click "Pull", not the "Sync" button).

If you want to undo your local changes, right click on your solution and click "Undo".

Comment: I went into the changes page and there's 218 entries in the Untracked Files list.  I've tried including them, excluding them, and undoing the changes, but it looks like the only thing I can do that will work is deleting them.  If I do this though is it just going to delete the changes I've made or will it delete the files themselves?

Comment: Did you create 218 files?  Or do the 218 files include things in your bin directory?  You probably need to add a .gitignore file in the root of your repository to ignore things that are created during a compile.  Here's the one recommended by github: https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore